# Bootstrap Behavior in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating an application with Tkinter that contains a grid of widgets. Is there anyway to mimic the behavior of bootstrap such that all the elements appear on the window after it is collapsed?

Comment: Could you ellaborate a bit on what it is you are trying to do?

Comment: Just as bootstrap responds to collapsing, this must respond in such a way that if the items are cut off after collapse, they move below to available space.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to insert elements in a tkinter window.
First you could use only yourelement.pack() to put the element, and every element you put after, it will be downside the first align at the center.
You could use `yourelement.pack()` and `yourelement.place(x=xx,y=xx,width=xx,height=xx)` to place the element where you want according to your x and y values.
And last of all but not less important, you could use `yourelement.grid(row=xx,column=xx)` to place the element in the window on a grid you have previously defined.
This last way to place the element is redimensionable, but a little bit difficult to assemble all the things in the window, but it's a thing of try and fail.